# How do I set the current working directory/drive in a dos batch file?

Tags: batch-file

`cd d:\projects` does not work

How can I set the current working drive and directory so that I can run msbuild scripts from there?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

try the following:

```
D:
cd \projects
```

or, in a single line (courtesy of [Kilanash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161989/how-do-i-set-the-current-working-directory-drive-in-a-dos-batch-file/3162001#comment3251896_3162001)):

```
cd /d D:\projects
```

Comment: or 'cd /d D:\projects' if you want it all in one line.

Comment: +1 to both. kilanash's is what I was looking for. but both of them worked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, script wouldn't work because of the (drive): part.. never would have guessed that!

Comment: For anyone who is interested/tired, you don't write `cd /e E:\projects` to switch to the e drive; It's still `/d`! :)

Answer (score 32):

This is also handy:

```
pushd D:\projects
```

You can then return to the directory you were previously at with:

```
popd
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about these commands. They're really handy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Launch `cmd` as current Windows Explorer directory:
https://superuser.com/questions/205359/how-to-open-command-prompt-in-current-folder-by-keyboard-shortcut
[Best AutoHotKey macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98597/best-autohotkey-macros/100648#100648)