# Get current path when running Python from Notepad++

Tags: python, windows, notepad++

I run Python scripts in Notepad++ using this command

```
cmd.exe /K "C:\InstallPython\python.exe" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

it works, but it works not great. 
When I run

```
exec(open("raw_ticker_list.lua").read())
```

it doesn't see the file, but it is in the same folder where the script lies.
When I run

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

it prints

[image]

How can I make python see files in current folder?

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161989/how-do-i-set-the-current-working-directory-drive-in-a-dos-batch-file

Comment: os.getcwd() gets the path where Python is running the script, not where the file sits.  What does it say when you print(__ file __)?

Comment: command exec(open("raw_ticker_list.lua").read()) is not working too. It doesn't see file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command instead:

```
cmd.exe /K "cd /D "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" & python "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)""
```

To recap, open the "Run" menu, select the "Run" entry, and enter the above command as "The Program to Run". Possibly "Save…" it and assign a name (and keyboard shortcut) so that it permanently appears in the "Run" menu going forward.

What it does is, it opens a command window, changes the working directory to that of the script currently active in the editor (across hard drives, hence the `/D` parameter), then runs the Python interpreter on the script, but keeps the command window open afterwards (the `/K` parameter).

Use the full path to `python.exe` instead of just `python` in case it's not on the Windows search path for executables.