# How do I use 'or's in AutoHotKey scripts?

Tags: conditional-statements, autohotkey

I have been browsing the [AutoHotKey documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm), and I don't see a clear use of how to use 'or' in context specific hot keys. On my setup, Cygwin will either launch with ahk_class cygwin (when I use the context menu) or mintty (when I use the .bat or exe directly).

Currently, I duplicate the hotkeys into two separate blocks,

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class cygwin
...
#IfWinActive
#IfWinActive ahk_class mintty
...
#IfWinActive
```

Is there a way to combine them? I've tried:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class cygwin ahk_class mintty
#IfWinActive ahk_class || cygwin ahk_class mintty
#IfWinActive ahk_class or cygwin ahk_class mintty
#IfWinActive ahk_class cygwin || #IfWinActive ahk_class mintty
#IfWinActive ahk_class cygwin or #IfWinActive ahk_class mintty
#IfWinActive (ahk_class cygwin or ahk_class mintty)
#IfWinActive (ahk_class cygwin || ahk_class mintty)
#IfWinActive ahk_class cygwin|mintty
#IfWinActive ahk_class cygwin||mintty
```

...and none of these seem to work. [This post](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/29477-ifwinactive-or-winactive/) states this can be accomplished with groups, but I'm looking for a way to combine them in a single statement.

Comment: What's wrong with duplicating them?

Comment: If I add a shortcut, I have to remember to add it twice. This could get cumbersome if it's more than 'just twice', and it's inelegant, and I'm looking for a way around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also try the following, I tested and it was working for me (AutoHotkey v1.1.14.01):

```
SetTitleMatchMode, REGEX

#IfWinActive (cygwin)|(mintty)
```

This uses the built-in OR mechanism of regular expressions. I couldn't get groups to work for some reason.

Comment: I had a similar problem. This seems to have worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

OK, last one (and tested).

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class ExploreWClass") || WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass")
```

Oh b.t.w. I use AutoHotKey_L, which supports #If!

Answer (score 8):

Alright, I remember, after seeing an other example: Define a GroupName with multiple ahk_class entries....

```
GroupAdd, GroupName, ahk_class ExploreWClass
GroupAdd, GroupName, ahk_class CabinetWClass
#IfWinActive ahk_group GroupName
```

Comment: Yeah, it looks like I'm going to have to resort to groups. In the purest form of the question, I was wondering if 'or' was possible (see the last line); it's looking like it isn't. If there isn't a proper or answer posted in a day or so, I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I should note, GroupAdd statements should be at the very beginning of your script, otherwise, it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is outdated, but for those who are looking for a solution to this

```
#if WinActive("ahk_class cygwin") or WinActive("ahk_class mintty")
```

is working.

Answer (score -1):

Could you try this: It is the way I do this with regular IF statements.

```
#IfWinActive (ahk_class cygwin or ahk_class mintty)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, either. I added it to the 'tried' list above.

Answer (score -1):

I found an example that uses this format:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class ExploreWClass|CabinetWClass
```

See: [Best AutoHotKey macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98597/best-autohotkey-macros)